# preventing form submit when button clicked

Tags: c#, jquery, html

I have a button within a form.
The thing is when I click it, it does not execute the server side function.
Is it possible to prevent form submission, while executing server functions and client side validations ?

Thanks in advance.

html (inside a form)

```
  <button class="submit" runat="server" id="v4"  onserverclick="v4_Click" >Validate</button>
```

jquery

```
 $('#v4').click(function (event) {
             if (validation()) {
                 slideToStep(5);
             }
             return false;
         });
```

c#

```
protected void v4_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("test");
        }
```

Comment: If you don't want to submit the form and still perform server function consider using ajax. Since you are returning false from handler it will never submit your form and execute server function. or just return false when your validation fails.

Comment: You are returning false everytime. how can it execute the server code.

Comment: You are using <asp:button/> instead of <button/>, right?

Comment: tried both with no luck

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can achieve what you're wanting, by binding the `event.preventDefault()` to the `submit` event of the form, rather than the `click` event of the button.

1. Setup an `onclick` for your button to call a function that submits your form.

   `<button class="submit" id="v4" onclick="SubmitForm();" runat="server" onserverclick="v4_Click" >Validate</button>`
2. Set the `SubmitForm()` function to submit the form, then bind a function to your submit event:

```
function SubmitForm() {
    $('#form1').submit();
}

$(function () {
    $('#form1').submit(function (event) {
        if (validation()) {
            slideToStep(5);
        }
        else
        {
            //Validation Failed, prevent form from submitting.
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `return false` does the same thing. and it is not submitting the form for OP. Read the question completely.

Comment: if i do preventDefault() the server will not execute v4_Click() because precventDefault() will prenvent it too.

Comment: Try my updated answer.  I think that binding the preventDefault to the submit event will allow the onserverclick function to be called.

Comment: form submit was not prevented with your solution, also the v4_click was not executed by the server

Answer (score 1):

`Is it possible to prevent form submission` yes it is
you can simply write `e.preventDefault()/Return false()` on jquery click of button

But again `While using server side function` i am not getting this

Comment: `return false` does the same thing. and it is not submitting the form for OP. Read the question completely.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your javascript code, in your case `return false` is always called, instead you should only call it when your validation fails:

```
$('#v4').click(function (event) {
     if (validation()) {
         slideToStep(5);
     } else{
         return false;
     }
});
```

Edit:

Basically, if you want to call the button_click event, you need to submit the form, in your case I would use a `WebMethod` to call a server side validation function with ajax. Something like this:

c#:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string Validate(string params)
{
    // your validations
    return "Received : " + params;
}
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#v4").click(function() {
     $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "Default.aspx/Validate",
      data: "{params: 5 }",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(msg) {
         alert(msg.d);
      }
});
```

Alternative:

You could also use a customValidator, and ASP will do all of the jquery stuff for you.

Comment: I dont want to submit the form, so i need to prevent it without prevent the onserverclick action of the button.

Comment: Almost getting it, beside the ajax is getting always on error alert.